# MySQL Count If DateDiff

Tags: mysql, count

I would like to count different conditions in one table:

```
SELECT gt.smechanic as 'Mech ID', 
       gm.mechanic_name as 'Mech Name', 
       count(gt.smechanic) as 'Total Invoices Not Received',
       count(if(datediff(gt.dispatch_date, curdate()) < 10,1,0)) as 'Within 10 days' 
from gt 
straight_join gm on gt.smechanic = gm.mechanic_id 
where gt.status = 3 or gt.status = 5 
group by gt.scheduled_mechanic
```

I am not sure if I am cancelling myself out with this statement because in both columns that I am counting the same value is returned.

Comment: Please share what the issue is with your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SUM()` in the second column, not `COUNT()`: COUNT merely counts records, it doesn't care if the value in them is 0 or 1. SUM, however, will return the total of all records that match your criterion.

```sql
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(gt.dispatch_date, CURDATE()) < 10, 1, 0))
```

Let me also point out that selecting non-aggregate columns that you aren't also grouping by leaves you vulnerable to unpredictable results. I would change that GROUP BY clause to

```sql
GROUP BY gt.smechanic, gm.mechanic_name
```